# how we can get data into controller with multiple select boxes inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to rendered selected data into the controller from the multiple drop down. which i declared one select box inside the ng-repeat tag.

this select box will repeat as much as the list size.

suppose my list size is 5.select box will repeats 5 times with the same data.
i have to get the selected data from the select box into the controller.
can anybody help me?

Here is the sample jsp code...

```
  <div ng-repeat="lanecategory in lanesList" >
    <div class="lanesclass" for="{{$index}}">
      <select ng-model="myLane"  style="width: 172px"  ng-options="myLane.lane for myLane in lanesList" id = "mylane{{$index}}"  ng-change="changeLanesSelList()" ></select>
      <select ng-model="myAssignment" style="width: 113px" ng-options="myAssignment.type for myAssignment in assignmentList"  id = "myAssignment{{$index}}" ></select>
      <input type="text"  ng-model="value" style="width: 125px;height: 34px" id = "value{{$index}}"/>
      <select ng-model="myOperation" style="width: 75px" class="form-control"  ng-options="myOperation.type for myOperation in operationList" id = "myOperation{{$index}}" ></select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

......

Comment: *Here is the sample jsp code* - where? Please post your code in order to get some help.

Comment: have edit your question, you might need to review the edit.

Comment: some body said this a reputation question but I did not found this type of question in forums.

Comment: @przno sample code is added how i able to get selected data(mylanes data,myassignment data,value and myoperation) into controller